# Change launcher icon on Flutter inside the app?

Tags: flutter, dart, launcher-icon

I want the user to be able to customize everything inside the app, this includes the **launcher icon**. I know some apps offer this feature, how can it be achieved with Flutter?

I normally use [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) to generate my launcher icon, works fantastic with or without flavors.

Example with images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this [article](https://medium.com/vijay-r/dynamically-change-app-launcher-icon-in-flutter-b6302c591ac1) on the medium from Sep 27, 2022 will help you.

You can also take a look at a couple of these plugins, I would advise you to write your own solution based on their code, because both plugins have not been updated for a long time.

- [flutter_dynamic_icon](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon)
- [dynamic_icon_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_icon_flutter)